# Go: Seek+Write vs WriteAt performance

Tags: performance, file, go

I've just started to study `Go`'s filesystem operations. It seems like there are at least two ways to perform random file writes:

```
// 1. First set the offset, then write data 
f.Seek(offset, whence)
f.Write(data)

// 2. Write by offset in one step
f.WriteAt(data, offset)
```

All of three functions (`Seek`, `Write`, `WriteAt`) are implemented with the use of different syscalls: on Unix systems `Write` is implemented via [`syscall.Write`](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go#L249) and `WriteAt` has [`syscall.Pwrite`](https://golang.org/src/os/file_unix.go#L275) inside.

Since `Seek+Write` perform two syscalls, whereas `WriteAt` requires only one syscall, should the second method be preferred for the sake of better performance?

Answer (score 2):

`seek()`+`read()` and `seek()` + `write()` are both a pair of sys-calls while `pread()` and `pwrite()` are single sys-calls. Less sys-calls - more efficiency.

You can definitly go for the `WriteAt`